# Subir archivos al servidor usando CodeIgniter y PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, fileupload

intento subir un archivo al servidor usando CodeIgniter y PHP, pero no hay manera de que se suba. Estoy algo perdido ya que he probado muchas formas de hacerlo. Os pongo las funciones que he hecho hasta ahora.

Esta es la parte en la que hago mendiante HTML y PHP el formulario donde intento cargar la imagen (vista):

```
<form action="subir" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="image">Imagen *</label>
      <input type="file" name="imagen" action="<?=base_url("subir_controller/subir")?>" method="post" value="<?=set_value('imagen')?>" />
```

Y esta es la clase que tengo la clase donde se supone que debería subirla (controlador):

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Archivo extends CI_Controller{

  public function index(){
    $this->load->view('nuevoProducto');
  }

  function subir(){
    $imagen = 'imagen';
    $config['upload_path'] = "asset/img/productos/";
    $config['file_name'] = "$imagen";
    $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|png";
    $config['max_size'] = "0";
    $config['max_width'] = "0";
    $config['max_height'] = "0";

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload($imagen)){
      $data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
      echo $this->upload->display_errors();
      return;
    }

    $data['uploadSuccess'] = $this->upload->data();
  }
}
```

Pero después de elegir la imagen con el navegador y darle en el formulario a finalizar (submit),  me crea el producto y tal, lo mete en la BD, es decir, hace todo, menos cargar la imagen del producto en el servidor, osea, que no la sube.

¿Me podéis echar una mano a ver si conseguimos ver dónde está el error?

Comment: intenta mostrar el display error, pero entiendo que ese resultado es un array, por ende, intenta mostrarlo con un print_r()

Comment: Dónde debería poner el print_r()? debajo de $data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();??

Comment: Has revisado los permisos en el directorio del servidor, como mínimo 755 ?

Comment: Deberia ser algo como esto... 

$data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data['uploadError']);
echo '</pre>';
die;

Comment: No me lanza ningún error, me pasa a la siguiente vista en la que me confirma la creación del producto, pero no me muestra ningún error

Comment: No creo que solucione el problema, pero tienes atributos inválidos en el input file, como `action` y `method`, que corresponden a la etiqueta `form`. Además, no puedes asignarle valor directamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tu formulario debe tener el **action** y el **method**:

```
<form action="<?= base_url('subir_controller/subir') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="image">Imagen *</label>
    <input type="file" name="imagen"/>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

La función `subir()` de tu controller, esta es la forma básica en la que procesarías la subida de la imagen:

1. Se carga la configuración.
2. Se verifica si el directorio donde quieres cargar la imagen existe.
3. Se carga e inicializa la librería **upload** con la configuración.
4. Se procede a cargar la imagen, si falla te retorna error, de lo contrario te retorna los datos de la carga de la imagen.

**Controlador**:

```
function subir()
{
    $config['upload_path']   = 'asset/img/productos/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite']     = true;
    $config['encrypt_name']  = false;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    if (!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) {
        die("El directorio de carga no existe");
    }
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('imagen')) {
        echo 'error';
    }
    else {
        return ['upload_data' => $this->upload->data()];
    }
}
```